# Determining the domain of a family of functions

Tags: calculus, functions

Currently preparing for a University entrance exam,so I took this mock exam yesterday, and this was one of the exercises in the Calculus part.

Assume that $ p > 0$. Determine the domain of the family of functions

$$f_(x) = \ln(-2x^2 + (4p-16)x + 32p) + 6$$

Now the expression

$-2x^2 + (4p-16)x + 32p  $ has to be positive, so I calculated the qudratic formula and got $16p^2 - 128p + 512$. This formula can be rewritten as $$16((p - 4)^2 +16 ) $$ so we conclude it's always positive. And then I stopped typing because I had no idea how to go from there.

So I would like to know the domain of the function above. Bear in mind that the domain must be constituted of exact numbers and not in function of $ p $.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is clear what OP asks.

Comment: For ant fixed $p$ the quadratic inside the ln in definition of f(x) takes on negative values for large x values. It is certainly not always positive as you say.

Comment: I meant the discriminant of the quadratic inside $ f(x) $ is postive. My bad I worded it terribly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$-2x^2 + (4p-16)x + 32p=(x-2p)(-2x-16)$$ and domain of log-function is $(0,\infty)$

Comment: Oh so the two factors have to positive at the same time which is impossible in this case or negative at the same time , we take the intersection of those intervals and that leaves us with (-8,0]. Thank you so much. It didn't occur to me to try to factorize the expression .

Comment: The domain of family is indeed (-8,0] . Because for $f_1$ is (-8,2) ,for $f_{0.5}$ is (-8,1)  and for $f_{0.25}$ is (-8,0.5) and so on... Now the domain of the family is the common domain of all such $ f_p's$ which  is (-8,0]..